# Table Cell Renderer for LocalTime

Tags: java, tablecellrenderer, localtime

I am new to programming and need help with rendering cells in a JTable.
I have implemented a custom cell renderer but don't know how to get custom components. getTableCellRendererComponent only accepts int,bool, table and Object.
Here is my code which works great with any of those data types.
But what i need to do is render the cells based on a LocalTime value and a String value. What am I missing?

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        //Here is what I want to accomplish with LocalTime values or String values
        if (SomeLocalTime > SomeOtherLocalTime)){
            c.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Please help

I got it working but now I cant render 2 different columns with different criteria. It's only returning the value from the second if where column ==3.
Do I need to have 2 TableCellRenderers for one table? Is that even possible and if so, how?
Here is my updated code:

```
public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (value instanceof Time && column == 2) {
            if (((Time) value).toLocalTime().isAfter(gracePeriodStartTime)) {
                c.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
        } else {
            c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }

        if (value instanceof Time && column == 3) {
            if (((Time) value).toLocalTime().isBefore(gracePeriodEndTime)) {
                c.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
        } else {
            c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (value instanceof LocalTime) { LocalTime lt = (LocalTime)value; }` - Remember, (are part from the primitives), everything extends from `Object`. You need to check type of `value` and make additional determinations beyond that, like `lt.after(LocalTime.now())` ;)

Comment: MadProgrammer, your advice helped immensely. Now I've hit another snag. Here is my updated code:

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is wrong:

```
if (SomeLocalTime.isAfter(SomeOtherLocalTime)) { 
    c.setForeground(Color.RED); 
} else { 
    c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
}
```

This should get you further along. Leave a comment if you need more help.